# DropDownListFor Value Field - Property Combination Identifer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm current wrestling with how to determine selected data from a `HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor` object.  The problem is that there is no single property of the model class that would be able to uniquely identify the model.

Below is my model and viewmodel classes, as well as a sample of the `HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor` call in the view.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }   // combined with ChildId is the unique identifier
    public int ChildId { get; set; }    // see above
    public string Name { get; set; }    // not unique
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

    public <???> SelectedItem { get; set; }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.MyModels, "DataValueField", "Name"))
```

The problem here is that the only unique idenfier of `MyModel` is the *combination* of `ParentId` and `ChildId`.  So what would be the best way to retrieve the data to uniquely identify the selected item?

To construct a unique identifier from one of these model objects would be similiar to the following (business logic):

```
ModelUniqueIdentifier = ParentId * 100 + ChildId
```

But I don't see any way to enforce this logic to set `MyViewModel.SelectedItem` to this.

When there is a postback from whatever triggers the form to submit, I'd like to be able to grab the selected value from the model's `SelectedItem` property in order to do other processing.  But with a one-dimensional `"DataValueField"`, I'm not sure the best way to accomplish this.

The most obvious way to circumvent this would be to inject a surrogate key into the data as a singleton identifier.  But with this particular data, there is just this obvious composite natural key that has been doing a great job up until this point.

So the two-dimensional data looks like:

```
ParentId    ChildId Name
7           3       Name1
4           8       Name2
5           3       Name3
4           6       Name4
```

If I was to add a surrogate key to the data it would do the job:

```
SurrogateId ParentId    ChildId Name
0           7           3       Name1
1           4           8       Name2
2           5           3       Name3
3           4           6       Name4
```

Whereas this would work, it would require me to change the underlying table, model, and a large amount of referencing code, so if I don't have to do add this surrogate key then I'd rather not.

Any thoughts or ideas?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your accepted answer will hardly solve the problem. You would not be able to bind the model on postback and if you get if from `Request.Form` how would you convert the value back to its `ParentId` and `ChildId` values? You could use a [pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) although I would recommend biting the bullet and correcting the database to give the table a unique ID field

Comment: I ended up working with a surrogate key in the data, and in turn the model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a calculated get property in your model that generates your unique ID on calling. Then pass 'UniqueId' as the data value field for the select list / dropdown. E.g.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int UniqueId { 
        get {
            return ParentId * 100 + ChildId;
        }
    }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }   // combined with ChildId is the unique identifier
    public int ChildId { get; set; }    // see above
    public string Name { get; set; }    // not unique
}
```

SelectItem would then be an int in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the thought, I see what you mean.  This would still cause me to have to alter my model class.  If there was any way around having to modify the class definition itself, that would be best.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, is there any reason you don't want to add to the model class? What do the ParentId and ChildId fields refer to? for example, is the ParentId and ChildId some sort of reciprocating relationship? So the ParentId references another Child in another record. Just trying to get my head around the data you're holding.

Comment: I ended up going with the surrogate key approach.  Thanks!

Comment: Great :).  Sorry I couldn't think of another way.